# How to select top 1 date from date column without timestamp?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select only one row register_date for each service from two tables.

But the output of query includes multiple rows if client has more rows with the same register_date.

How can I solve this issue?

I have to select from two tables.

- tServices
- tRegister

My code is:

```
  SELECT tServices.Client_id, tRegister.register_date, 
         tServices.type_service, 
         tServices.start_date, tServices.end_date
  FROM tServices INNER JOIN tRegister
         ON tRegister.Client_id = tServices.ClientId AND 
            tServices.type_service IN (3,2)
  WHERE tRegister.register_date = 
                          (SELECT top 1 tRegister2.register_date
                          FROM tRegister as tRegister2
                          WHERE tRegister2.ClientId = tServices.ClientId
                          ORDER BY tRegister2.register_date asc)
```

---

The output looks like below for one client, but I want to see one row in output.

```
 Client_Id  register_date   Type_Service    Start_Date  End_Date

  1001    21-11-2018             2        17-01-2019    19-3-2019
  1001    21-11-2018             2        17-12-2018    19-3-2019
```

Comment: Can you provide data and/or logic which would explain how you want to break a tie, should a client have more than one row with the same earliest registration date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` operator for this:

```
select *
from tServices s
  cross apply (
  select top (1) * from tRegister r
  where r.Client_id = s.ClientId
  order by r.register_date
) ca;
```

Note that there are 2 versions of `apply`:

- `cross` (which is the equivalent of an `inner` join);
- `outer`, which works as a `left outer` join.

In the query above, you won't see any rows from `tServices` for clients that have no registrations. If you still need them, replace `cross` with `outer`.